# Java ImageIO: ClassNotFoundException at first call in OSGI compliant Protege

Tags: java, plugins, osgi, javax.imageio, protege

I am developing an ontology display plugin for the Protege application, which is OSGI compliant. The graphics library I inherited is Prefuse, which is *NOT* OSGI compliant and calls ImageIO to save an image of the display. I have read there are initialization issues calling outside the OSGI framework but nothing I have tried has resolved the ClassNotFoundException being thrown by ImageIO, and I haven't been able to catch the exception.

The IDE is IntelliJ IDEA, and Java version is Java 8.

Is there some initialization that will "find" the ImageIO library from within the OSGI framework?

Here is the code that throws the error:

```
public class SaveDisplayAction extends AbstractAction {

    private Display display;
    private JFileChooser chooser;
    private ScaleSelector scaler;
    private BufferedImage bufferedImage;

    /**
     * Create a new SaveDisplayAction for the given Display.
     * @param display the Display to capture
     */
    public SaveDisplayAction(Display display) {
        this.display = display;
    }

    private void init() {
        boolean useCache = ImageIO.getUseCache(); //     **<-- throws ClassDefNotFoundException**
    }


    /**
     * Shows the image export dialog and processes the results.
     * @see java.awt.event.ActionListener#actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // lazy initialization
        if ( chooser == null )
            init();
    }
}
```

Here is the exception being thrown. The application proceeds but any further calls to the ImageIO library throw similar exceptions.

```
17:17:41.377 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR o.p.editor.core.ProtegeApplication - Uncaught Exception in thread 'AWT-EventQueue-0'
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/imageio/ImageIO
    at org.visualdataweb.vowl.controlView.SaveDisplayAction.init(SaveDisplayAction.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.visualdataweb.vowl.controlView.SaveDisplayAction.actionPerformed(SaveDisplayAction.java:119) ~[classes/:na]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) [na:1.8.0_231]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.imageio.ImageIO not found by org.visualdataweb.boa.protege [20]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1574) ~[org.apache.felix.main-5.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79) ~[org.apache.felix.main-5.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018) ~[org.apache.felix.main-5.4.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

During compilation I get this Warning message:

```
Warning:osgi: [boa] Bundle-Activator org.protege.editor.core.plugin.DefaultPluginActivator is being imported into the bundle rather than being contained inside it. This is usually a bundle packaging error
```

If I add javax.imageio to the Maven import section the plugin fails when attempting to activate. I assume it is because javax.imageio is not an OSGI compliant bundle?

```
09:55:00.817 [FelixStartLevel] ERROR o.p.o.framework.FrameworkSlf4jLogger - Error starting file:/C:/Users/kcason/Documents/IdeaProjects/HPM/Protege/Protege-5.5.0-beta-3/plugins/boa-1.1.0.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.visualdataweb.boa.protege [20](R 20.0): missing requirement [org.visualdataweb.boa.protege [20](R 20.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.imageio.ImageIO) Unresolved requirements: [[org.visualdataweb.boa.protege [20](R 20.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.imageio.ImageIO)]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111) ~[org.apache.felix.main-5.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117) ~[org.apache.felix.main-5.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1371) ~[org.apache.felix.main-5.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308) [org.apache.felix.main-5.4.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_231]
```

Answer (score 1):

The bundle `org.visualdataweb.boa.protege` uses the class `ImageIO` and runs into an error. This indicates the package `javax.imageio` is not imported by this bundle. If the package had been imported you would have had an error during resolving. However, you get the error when the first class is loaded so it cannot be properly imported.

Since this is almost impossible to do with [bndtools](https://bndtools.org), I assume you use PDE as your development environment? In that case, you should add the import for `javax.imageio` to the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file.

If this is not the issue you have to provide more information.

*In general, when you report such an error, the development environment you use is quite crucial to provide correct support. Nowadays the JVM  version is also crucial but I could see it in the stack trace that you use 1.8.*

Answer (score 0):

I added javax.imageio.ImageIO to the Maven import section and received all the errors above. When I shortened it to javax.imageio (as suggested by Peter above) it worked!